# hiding background color overflow HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, background, background-color

I'm trying to put a background color shape, like a big div rotate on the background of my website but the problem is when I place this background where I want it to be its creating me a big margin right & bottom ( because of the end of that div that I have created for putting my background )

here is what I have done :

```css
.fill-2{
    position: absolute;
    top: 45%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -2;
    background-color: #A08823;
    opacity: 30%;
    height: 200vh;
    -moz-transform: rotate(20deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(20deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(20deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(20deg);
    transform: rotate(20deg);  
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="fill-1"></div>
    <div class="container">
        <!-- my content -->
    </div>
    <div class="fill-2"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is a bit unclear, but here are some hints:
The absolutely positioned (background) element should be a *child*  element of your main element. Then you can apply `position: relative;`, `overflow: hidden;` and optionally a fixed `height` to the main element (`.container` in my example below), which will hide those parts of the background that go beyond the main element:

```css
.fill-2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -2;
  background-color: #A08823;
  opacity: 30%;
  height: 200vh;
  -moz-transform: rotate(20deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(20deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(20deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(20deg);
  transform: rotate(20deg);
}

.container {
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="fill-1"></div>
  <div class="container">
    <!-- my content -->
    <div class="fill-2"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

If by "big margin" you mean that the shape extends over the viewport and the scrollbars appear, then you should set `overflow: hidden;` on your parent element, in your case `<body>`, like so:

```css
.fill-2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -2;
  background-color: #a08823;
  opacity: 30%;
  height: 200vh;
  -moz-transform: rotate(20deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(20deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(20deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(20deg);
  transform: rotate(20deg);
}

body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="fill-1"></div>
  <div class="container">
    <!-- my content -->
  </div>
  <div class="fill-2"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: yes mate that's what I meant but the problem is when I do an overflow hidden all the rest of my viewport is hidden so I can't scroll for the rest of the website

Comment: @wldblm I see. Then instead just use "overflow-x: hidden;". That will hide only x-axis

Answer (score 0):

add overflow: hidden;
I hope that will work!
cheers!